Cannot use the editor function "Play" in this runtime blueprint. Only for use in Editor Utility Blueprints and Blutilities
How can I solve the error: "Cannot use the editor function "Play" in this runtime blueprint. Only for use in Editor Utility Blueprints and Blutilities"?

b2.png

You are attempting to access a deleted or non-existent Actor in a level Blueprint.
Level Blueprints can only access objects that exist in the level at build time.
Fix the unknown variable reference by deleting and recreating it from a valid object in the level.
